# Web API is accessible from MVC code but gives 404 error when accessed from website

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We have deployed Web APIs on test server on IIS. And those Web APIs are accessible from Asp.net MVC Application Project. However after deploying that MVC Web application on same server, Web APIs are not accessible from deployed MVC website. We are getting Error: "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

Those Web APIs running fine from Postman also.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

            var task = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiPath, request);
            var response = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = BusinessUtility.ConvertJsonToObject<T>(response);
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Ensure that variable `apiBaseURL` hold correct api url. After deployment ensure that your mvc app code is using the deployed web api url instead of localhost

Comment: Yes. variables are passed correctly(coming from DB). Because APIs are executed well when run from MVC code. However when same application is deployed, it is unable to execute APIs, giving 404 error. Am I missing something in deployement/configuration?

Comment: Can you share code where `apiBaseURL` variable is populating

Comment: string apiBaseURL = BusinessUtility.GetServiceURL(serviceType);

            Logger.Log("APIBaseURL :" + apiBaseURL);
            Logger.Log("APIPath :" + apiPath);

Comment: I've even logged baseUrl & api URL to check whether they are correct. Variables are populating it correctly. Please check below log.

08:57:31 PM :- APIBaseURL : http://sidcdvmyretail.in.ril.com/AuthenticationService/
08:57:31 PM :- APIPath :api/Authentication/Login

Comment: Do you have any endpoint on the AuthenticationController that can be executed using GET request by anonymous users? If not, I suggest add one returning simple string response and then try accessing after deployment. This will ensure that API is correctly setup on the server